# I am trying to understand what the function "reorder_sentence" does in this link:

Tags: python, nltk

```
def reorder_sentences( self, output_sentences, input ):
        output_sentences.sort( lambda s1, s2:
            input.find(s1) - input.find(s2) )
        return output_sentences
```

https://github.com/thavelick/summarize/blob/master/summarize.py

I know briefly what lambda is but i dont understand the context of the method "reorder_sentence" in this code. what are s1 and s2 and how is the method exactly working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in a def statement would be

```
def function(s1, s2):
    return input.find(s1) - input.find(s2)
```

The result of this function is then passes into the sort method as the key.

lambdas are used for short functions where defining a full function would be unnecessary, eg

```
adder = lambda x, y: x + y
adder(1, 2)
>>> 3
```